# Rellenar listas de una clase desde la clase main

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
package modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import enums.NombresTiendas;

public class Compradores {

    private String nombre;
    private Boolean habitual;
    private Integer mediaGasto;
    private List<NombresTiendas> nomTiendaLST;

    public Compradores() {

    }

    public Compradores(String nombreAux, Boolean habitualAux,
            Integer mediaGastoAux, List<NombresTiendas> nomTiendaLSTAux) {
        nombre = nombreAux;
        habitual = habitualAux;
        mediaGasto = mediaGastoAux;

        if (nomTiendaLSTAux != null) {
            nomTiendaLST = nomTiendaLSTAux;
        } else {
            nomTiendaLST = new ArrayList<NombresTiendas>();
        }

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombreAux) {
        nombre = nombreAux;
    }

    public Boolean getHabitual() {
        return habitual;
    }

    public void setHabitual(Boolean habitualAux) {
        habitual = habitualAux;
    }

    public Integer getMediaGasto() {
        return mediaGasto;
    }

    public void setMediaGasto(Integer mediaGastoAux) {
        mediaGasto = mediaGastoAux;
    }

    public List<NombresTiendas> getNomTiendaLST() {
        return nomTiendaLST;
    }

    public void setNomTiendaLST(List<NombresTiendas> nomTiendaLSTAux) {
        nomTiendaLST = nomTiendaLSTAux;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return nombre + " es un cliente de El Corte Inglés, " + habitual
                + " es habitual en la tienda. Gasta una media de " + mediaGasto
                + " € al año. Sin duda, su tienda favorita es " + nomTiendaLST;
    }

}
```

Lo que quiero saber es si es posible, desde una clase main, editar, añadir, eliminar elementos a las listas que tengo aquí creadas, estas listas vienen de otros archivos enumerados, pero de todas formas me gustaría saber si esto es posible aunque fuera una lista normal y corriente, espero estar explicándome.

O si por el contrario tengo que rellenar las listas dentro de la propia clase que he creado. Estoy empezando en Java, haciendo un curso y ahora mismo tengo la cabeza un poco loca entre tanto término nuevo, por eso estoy algo liado, muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas de antemano.

Comment: Parece que se ha comido el saludo inicial del post, pero no me deja corregirlo, lo siento :(

Comment: Si los atributos del objeto son privados, no. Para eso tienes que crear una función publica que lo haga, y llamarla desde el main

Answer (score -1):

Si se puede, yo modificaría los datos de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    //nose como tienes definida la clase nombrestiendas asi que hize una con solo un dato llamado nombre
    //para definir el nombre llamo al metodo setNombre y para traer el nombre uso el metodo getNombre
    NombresTiendas tienda1 =  new NombresTiendas();//creo un objeto de la clase NombresTiendas y le doy el nombre
    tienda1.setNombre("tienda 1");
    NombresTiendas tienda2 =  new NombresTiendas();//creo otro objeto y hago lo mismo
    tienda2.setNombre("tienda 2");

    List<NombresTiendas> lista = new ArrayList<>(); //creo una lista
    //agrego los objetos creados tienda1 y tienda 2
    lista.add(tienda1);
    lista.add(tienda2);

    Compradores comprador1 = new Compradores();
    comprador1.setNombre("Juan Lopez");
    comprador1.setHabitual(true);
    comprador1.setMediaGasto(12);
    comprador1.setNomTiendaLST(lista);


    //Muestro el nombre de la tienda1 
    String nombre = comprador1.getNomTiendaLST().get(0).getNombre();
    System.out.println(nombre);
    //si Quieres editar el nombre de la tienda1 ingresada a comprador1
    comprador1.getNomTiendaLST().get(0).setNombre("tienda 3");//uso el metodo setNombre
    nombre = comprador1.getNomTiendaLST().get(0).getNombre();
    System.out.println(nombre);


}
```